# Can we use a leg to play the ball in volleyball?

Tags: rules, volleyball

I have started playing volleyball recently, and I fully admit I don't know the rules of the game in great detail.

Recently when we were playing, one of us played the ball with their leg and then another player continued the rally. Is this a foul?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to one [LiveStrong.com page](http://www.livestrong.com/article/467549-legal-illegal-hits-in-volleyball/) discussing legal and illegal volleyball hits:

> **Recently Updated Rules**
>
> **Contacting the ball with any part of the body below the waist used to be illegal. When the ball hits any part of your body, including the
> leg or the foot, it constitutes a legal hit.** Another USA Volleyball
> rule update for the 2010 season slightly changed the rule regarding
> physical support for a teammate. Previously you couldn't get a
> teammate's help to reach a ball. Now you can't get a teammate's help
> to hit the ball, although it is still legal for a teammate to stop you
> or hold you back from touching the net or crossing the center line.

According to [another site](http://www.strength-and-power-for-volleyball.com/rules-of-volleyball.html), volleyball rules state:

> **The volleyball may touch any part of the body.**

Finally, from the official USA Volleyball site, the [2009-11 US domestic indoor rules](http://www.volleyball.com/rules/usa_volleyball_indoor_rules_final.pdf) state:

> 9.2 CHARACTERISTICS OF THE HIT
>
> **9.2.1  The ball may touch any part of the body.**

Similarly, the [2011-12 FIVB international rules](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/Documents/FIVB.2011-2012.VB.RulesOfTheGame.Eng.TextfileOnly.2.1.1.pdf) state:

> **9.2.1  The ball may touch any part of the body**

So for all major indoor court competitions, rule 9.2.1 permits hits by any part of the body.

For beach volleyball, FIVB has a similar rule in the 2009-12 rules:

> **13.4.1 The ball may touch any part of the body.**

So by the currently available rules, players can legally hit the ball with any part of the body.

Comment: You mention indoor. Is this to imply that it would be different for outdoor volleyball?

Comment: @corsiKa, good point. Looked up the FIVB beach volleyball rules - similar rule is in place.

Comment: Is this valid for pass only? Can I make a hit with leg?

Comment: Use of the legs is valid in any situation except to serve but using the hands is more precise and the only real possibility to effectively spike the ball due to the height of the net.